# How does the AppBundles of Forge Configurator work?

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

i'm trying to extract and run the AppBundles from this demo written in C#

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor

I don't know anything about C# (i use php to program) and i need to integrate this Forge Configurator in my site but i don't understand how the AppBundles works

Can someone explain to me how to run the AppBundles?

(i already run other AppBundle on forge, but there was documentation on each of them, with input/output parameters, ecc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the **zip** of each **app bundle** inside the **release zip** file: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/releases/download/v1.0.355/ForgeConvInv-Release-win7-x64-1.0.355.zip

Inside the **appsettings.json** file you can find what name is used for each of them when they are uploaded to **Forge**: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/appsettings.json

Inside this folder you'll find how the **activities** are set up, inc the input/output **parameters** and **commandLine** they use: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/tree/master/WebApplication/Processing

e.g. **CreateBOM** **commandLine** https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/Processing/CreateBOM.cs#L37 and **output parameter** https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/Processing/CreateBOM.cs#L30

Concerning the format of the input **json** file that is used by **UpdateParameters activity**: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/Processing/UpdateParameters.cs#L55 you can find the structure here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/Shared/InventorParameters.cs